# How to display the combobox selected value in textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am working on WPF application. I have a window which has "Combobox" and "Textboxes". Well, I want to display the selected combobox values in textbox. (Combo Box displays the concatenated string firstname+lastname+initials).  But I have two text box for firstname & second name. I want to display only "firstname" in first text box and "last name" in second text box. 
I wrote the below code. IT displays the values but concatenated. IS there any way I can just display first name in first text box and last name in second text box. 
Thanks.

```
FNSysEngnrTextBox.Text = SysEngnrCB.SelectedItem.ToString
LNSysEngnrTextBox.Text = SysEngnrCB.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Comment: What does the ComboBox text look like, any type of delineation of the fields? and I am presumming Vb.net?

Comment: It displays values like this: William,Holl{HW}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SelectedItem` is an `Object` you get the full Type prefacing your data when you use the `ToString` Method. I was able to get the result you were looking for by using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx#Y1082). See if this works for you.

```
Dim delineators() As Char = {":", ",", "{", "}"}
Dim substrings() As String = SysEngnrCB.SelectedItem.ToString.Split(delineators)
FNSysEngnrTextBox.Text = substrings(1)
LNSysEngnrTextBox.Text = substrings(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not particular familiar with your platform, but I think
LNSysEngnrTextBox.Text should be

LNSysEngnrTextBox.Value or LNSysEngnrTextBox.Val

Comment: TextBox.Text is a valid property in VB.Net and WPF